# Query for searching multiple user inputs in HTML text field for multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

We have a HTML search page, having multiple text fields to search.

The user can input as many values as he want in text field and on submit, the query should return appropriate results.

We have different tables as

- candidate
- candidate_contact
- company
- etc.

Example:

User enters like **candidate** should have java skills also lives in California but should not have experience less than 2 years.

These records can be in same or different tables (like skills and country in same table and exp in another table)

Its like including and excluding search result.

```
$query = array();
if (!empty($_POST['keyword_s_dec'])) 
{
 $query[] = "candidate.cand_desc = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword_s_dec'])."'";
 $join.="JOIN candidate_contact ON candidate.cand_desc=candidate_contact.cand_id"; 
 //$join.="select * from candidate join candidate_contact ON candidate.cand_number=candidate_contact.cand_id WHERE candidate.cand_desc='".$_POST['keyword_s_dec']."'";
 }
 if (!empty($_POT['keyword_s_location'])) 
 {
  $query[] = "candidate_contact.cand_location = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword_s_location;'])."'";///edit
  $join.=" AND JOIN candidate_contact ON candidate.cand_number=candidate_contact.cand_id";
 } 

//$condition = implode(' AND ', $query);
$condition = implode(' AND ', $query);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM candidate".$join.' where '.$condition;

where - candidate is my main table and candidate_contact is another table.
where -cand_desc is database column in candidate & keyword_s-dec is text field id.
where- cand_location is my database column in candidate_contact and keywors_s_location is text field id.

This code is being slightly guided by one of stack overflow member and we though this should be edit to get more precised to the problem.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT candidate.*,candidate_contact.feild_name1,candidate_contact.feild_name2
FROM candidate 
LEFT JOIN candidate_contact  
ON candidate.cand_number=candidate_contact.cand_id where $condition
```

Note:- add the table name with .(dot)in the where clause to define which feild name you want to do the comparision   as shown in selection field area of the query and can continue joinning different tables in the same way as above before the where clause.

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: We have 20 fields, user can input field he want and it should combine and show result only for inputted fields and exclude remaining.As example provided, we have skills,location,designation, gender,age etc...  user if entered skills and gender it should search for only that fields, exclude the remaining.

Comment: for that you have to add another variable in your if condition which contain the join query string and just using the .(dot) operator concate it with the same in different IF condition so the output of the new variable only contain the joining query for which user have given the input nad then pass the variable in your query string just like you have done for condition

Comment: @karvin.developer..I did get you upto some point, but can you show me some skeleton view of the if condition you told above so that I can have a cleared view of the query. Thank you.

Comment: use this
`if(!empty($_POST[feild1])){

$query[]=<your code>;
$join='LEFT join <table name you want to join> ON <the joining condtion>';

}`

`if(!empty($_POST[feild2])){

$query[]=<your code>;
$join.='LEFT join <table name you want to join> ON <the joining condtion>';//see i have use the .(dot after $join) 
`
and now in you `$sql="select <selecting feild name with table name> $join where $condition";`

Comment: its not displaying the results. You have mention $join as another query and concatenated with $query right. If $join gets concatenated(.dot) with $query so what can be the problem to display the results. 
if(condition) { $query=condition..... $join.=query}
       $condition = implode(' AND ', $query);     
 $sql = query....AND $condition ;   
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());   
echo "in result";  //its printing in results..till here...not going in while loop to fetch records.

Comment: `$sql="select <feilds to be selected > from <primary table> ".$join.' where '.$condition;` will create a single sql query statement which will be executed

Comment: we have tried above $join and $sql query as it is but its giving error: " You have an error in your SQL syntax;"
we have modified to : $sql = "SELECT * FROM candidate'".$join."' where '".$condition."'";
But here it is giving error as: You have an error in your SQL syntax; near ''' where '''

Comment: yes because you have to use <space> after the candidate and before the where

Comment: Thank you for your help, but its still giving error. We tried :-
echo $query; echo $condition; and echo $join. every variable is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($_POST['keyword_s_dec'])) 
{
$query[] = "candidate.cand_desc = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword_s_dec'])."'";
$join.=" JOIN candidate_contact ON candidate.cand_number=candidate_contact.cand_id"; 
}
if (!empty($_POST['keyword_s_preflocation'])) 
{
$query[] = "candidate_contact.cand_location = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword_s_preflocation'])."'";///edit
//$join.=" LEFT JOIN candidate_contact ON candidate.cand_number=candidate_contact.cand_id";
}

$condition = implode(' AND ', $query);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM candidate ".$join.' where '.$condition;
```

@karvin.developer If the join condition gets same it won't work. I made some mistakes but re-read your statements from the start and it worked for me like heaven. Thank you karvin.developer :)